# CakePHP 2.4 ignoring view

Tags: php, cakephp

I can't figure out at the moment why my view is not being displayed.

Controller: (/app/Controller/EventsController.php)

```
<?php

class EventsController extends AppController 
{
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    function index() {
        $data = $this->Event->find('all');
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }

}

?>
```

View: (/app/View/Events/index.ctp)

```
<?php

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $data[$i]['Event']['Id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data[$i]['Event']['Start'] . "</td>";
    echo "<tr>";

}

echo "<table>";
//die;
?>
```

However, if I just uncomment **die;** in my last line the content appears. So it's not like it's being skipped, it's more like being ignored afterwards.

Not sure if needed but my routes.php is pretty much standard:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'index', 'home'));

Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

CakePlugin::routes();

require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Comment: Did you intend to pass `home` to the event controller's index action? Also, your field names break CakePHP's [naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html) by using capital case, which may cause issues with your application.

Comment: Also, you should be _closing_ your <tr> and <table> elements, where your above example shows you re-opening these tags.

Comment: Removed 'home' and closed the tags, also renamed the Id and Start field to "id" / "start". This didn't help though, the issue still exists.

Comment: Use [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) to review the contents of your `$data` variable, or dump the contents of it from the view.

Comment: Accidentally removed my `$this->fetch('content')`. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally removed my `echo $this->fetch('content');` in my default.ctp under /app/View/Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 'echo $this->fetch('content')' in your layout file.